# Which button redirects me to the key chests in Pixel Gun 3D?

Tags: pixel-gun-3d

I got some keys and I know that they passed 10+ after playing a deathmatch in Pixel Gun 3D. Since the game has a bunch of locations, I cannot find the key chests. (I remember the lockers as  a recommendation.) I checked Armory multiple times (Not all armory items are in armory) and not finding them.

For clarification, the key chests, are not called "key chests", I call them that because I forget the title after all the alternatives in the game. It is this section in the game where the key chests are blue, purple, and the last one I figure red. The prices are 10 keys,  50 keys, and I forgot the last price for the red one. They are these raffle chests to where you see what price they are giving you, like common rewards like coins or gems, or big rewards like gear gun pieces or mythical x1 pieces, such as trails and rifles. If you have saw this background before, please notify the navigation buttons in your answer. [See more detail here.](https://pixelgun.fandom.com/wiki/Key)

> The keys can only be spent on opening Small Chests, King Chests, and Mega Chests. In the old Super Lottery, it would be used for obtaining Novice Chests, Fighter Chests, and Winner Chests.

So, I guess that is what they are called.

In all, can someone please show me the buttons to the key chests?

Answer (score 3):

To your surprise, I *am* familiar with this game.

I assume you're referring to the lottery, right? They have chests that you open with keys to get cool prizes.

In a nutshell:

[image]

And in there:

[image]

So as you can see, you were *kind of* right. Blue (novice) chest is ten keys. Typically useless. Has underpowered epic and rare guns. Yellow chest (fighter, or "king" in gamedev event) costs 50 keys. Has fair supply of epic and rare guns. Of course they are stronger than those in blue chest. Red chest (mega chest) costs 250 keys. I promise you this **is** possible to get without solid money. Has cool legendary guns. Gives a ton of parts for single weapon. And purple chest, is super chest. Gives 150 parts for mythical weapon!! It's supposed to be a bonus for reaching a 1000 points after opening a lot of chests. Now I think this one is only possible with P2W (pay-to-win).

What I typically do is, open all blue chests first, get the free trash guns (I want to collect them) and then continue with yellow chests and so on. If I feel yellow chests are useless that time I just go for red chests. I can manage about 2 in a single event.

Then we have a "general bullet set". This isn't totally what you're looking for. It's easier to get weapons here, though. And the mammoth is overrated.

Have fun!